# Data structure for very large binary data

Tags: data-structures, binary, language-agnostic

I'm building a Genetic Algorithm and I was wondering what's a good data structure to use for encoding the chromosomes (essentially a long sequence of 0s and 1s).

I'm aiming for efficiency in changing bits at random within the chromosomes and performing crossovers between chromosomes. Essentially a lot of copying and changing of bits or sub sequences of bits.

So far I'm just stuck with a plain Boolean array but I feel like there should be a better data structure for efficiently handling very large amounts of binary data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: a BitSet? essentially a wrapper around an array of int accessing indvidual bits

Comment: My problem isn't really space allocation tho, more about efficiency to manipulate. Isn't a bitset essentially an array that more efficiently deals with space?

Comment: it is. but it doesn't have to be poorly performing. Bit masking operations are fast.

Comment: I'm not going to do that much intense bit masking though (sure i will flip some bits) but I'm more worried about efficient copying, duplicating sub sequences etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to using int primitives to represent groups of binary values and using bitwise operations and masks to change the groups of binary values could gain you large speed increases depending on how you are manipulating data. You could randomly mutate blocks of genes at a time using randomly generated masks.

An array is hard to beat if you are scanning the whole thing or know the index ahead of time. However, copying sections of the array over other sections can be challenging, but its still reasonably efficient.

If you are more concerned with swapping fixed sized groups of genes, building a 2 level tree with n branches with the groups of genes on each leaf would allow you to swap groups of genes very fast. The groups might not need to be the same size either. If you the genes need to be broken up further into chromosomes, you can add an intermediate level to the tree.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm reading so far from my researches. I'm working in C# and could use BitArray but this is again only for space saving, bool array is just very fast already I guess.

Comment: Dividing the genes up into groups and building a tree structure will allow you to very quickly swap branches or leaves of the tree. This is probably closer to what you want. It requires more memory to store and other operations will suffer (to varying degrees depending on how you build the tree), but it should optimize for what you are doing.